# Current Location does not update on a real device

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, xcode-6.2, ios8.2

I am new in iOS Development. My issue is that when I want to try get current location on real device but it is not working and give me following error:

```
Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for location authorization. Must call -[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization] first.
```

I am using Xcode 6.2 and the source code is as follows:

```
////.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@protocol LocationViewDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)sendLocationLatitude:(double)latitude
                  longitude:(double)longitude
                 andAddress:(NSString *)address;
@end

@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<LocationViewDelegate> delegate;

- (instancetype)initWithLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)locationCoordinate;
@end

////.m
#import "HomeViewController.h"
#import "anotation.h"
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import "LocationViewController.h"

//In ViewDidLoad

#define IS_OS_8_OR_LATER ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)

static LocationViewController *defaultLocation = nil;

@interface HomeViewController () <MKMapViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate> {

    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    MKMapView *_mapView;
    MKPointAnnotation *_annotation;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D _currentLocationCoordinate;
    BOOL _isSendLocation;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *addressString;
@end

@implementation HomeViewController

@synthesize addressString = _addressString;

- (instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {

    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        _isSendLocation = YES;
    }

    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)locationCoordinate {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        _isSendLocation = NO;
        _currentLocationCoordinate = locationCoordinate;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;

    float fOSVersion=[[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];

    if(fOSVersion>=8.0) {

        [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
        CLAuthorizationStatus status = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];
        if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
            [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        } else {
            [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        }
    }

    UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 44)];
    [backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    // [backButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"back", @"") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton addTarget:self.navigationController action:@selector(popViewControllerAnimated:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIView *backButtonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 63, 33)];
    //  backButtonView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    backButtonView.bounds = CGRectOffset(backButtonView.bounds, 45, 5);
    [backButtonView addSubview:backButton];

    UIBarButtonItem *backItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButtonView];

    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:backItem];

    _mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    _mapView.delegate = self;
    _mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
    _mapView.zoomEnabled = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:_mapView];

    if (_isSendLocation) {
        _mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;//显示当前位置

        UIButton *sendButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 44)];
        UIView *avatarButtonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(290, 0, 63, 33)];
        [sendButton setTitle:@"发送" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [sendButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor]forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [sendButton addTarget:self action:@selector(sendLocation) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        //avatarButtonView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        avatarButtonView.bounds = CGRectOffset(avatarButtonView.bounds, -25, 5);
        [avatarButtonView addSubview:sendButton];

        UIBarButtonItem *avatarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:avatarButtonView];
        [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:avatarItem];
        //        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = ;

        [self startLocation];
    }
    else {

        [self removeToLocation:_currentLocationCoordinate];
    }   
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma marks StatusBar
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {

    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return NO;
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

#pragma mark - class methods

+ (instancetype)defaultLocation {

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        defaultLocation = [[LocationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    });

    return defaultLocation;
}

#pragma mark - MKMapViewDelegate

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {

    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:userLocation.location completionHandler:^(NSArray *array, NSError *error) {
        if (!error && array.count > 0) {
            CLPlacemark *placemark = [array objectAtIndex:0];
            weakSelf.addressString = placemark.name;

            [self removeToLocation:userLocation.coordinate];
        }
    }];
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didFailToLocateUserWithError:(NSError *)error
{
}

#pragma mark - public

- (void)startLocation {

    if (_isSendLocation) {

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
    }
}

-(void)createAnnotationWithCoords:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coords {

    if (_annotation == nil) {
        _annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    }
    else{
        [_mapView removeAnnotation:_annotation];
    }
    _annotation.coordinate = coords;
    [_mapView addAnnotation:_annotation];
}

- (void)removeToLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)locationCoordinate {

    _currentLocationCoordinate = locationCoordinate;
    float zoomLevel = 0.01;
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(_currentLocationCoordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(zoomLevel, zoomLevel));
    [_mapView setRegion:[_mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];

    if (_isSendLocation) {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;
    }

    [self createAnnotationWithCoords:_currentLocationCoordinate];
}

- (void)sendLocation {

    if (_delegate && [_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(sendLocationLatitude:longitude:andAddress:)]) {
        [_delegate sendLocationLatitude:_currentLocationCoordinate.latitude longitude:_currentLocationCoordinate.longitude andAddress:_addressString];
    }

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {

    if (status != kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: Check this tutorial http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/

Comment: Dear   Yogesh Suthar please chek my source code and advice me thanku

Comment: thanks now it is working fine on my device

Comment: can we add other locations with cureent location??

Answer (score 0):

Change here

```
 if (status != kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
```

To

```
if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
            [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        }
```

And Delete

```
CLAuthorizationStatus status = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];
    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    } else {
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
```

If you have not add NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in your plist
add it to describe why you want to use location service

Comment: but i could not vote because my Reputation is now down only 15+ can vote

Comment: Can i Get also Lat LONg and adress string if yes then share with me source code lat long in this formate 0.23454554 etc and adress street8